# Material choice for a rigid spacer between a stem wall, floating floor and plaster stop?

Tags: materials, flooring

By design, I have a ~1-1/2" vertical and horizontal gap between the floating hardwood floor I installed and the metal plaster stop at the base of the interior walls, as shown below: [image: ~1-1/2" gap between floor and wall].

As shown above, this gap exposes the concrete stem wall along the wall perimeter; the plaster stop protrudes ~1-1/2" from the stem wall to create the effect of a floating wall.

I'd like to install some material against the stem wall, both to nicely cover the exposed concrete and also to add a rigid support/shim that will help to hold the oak floor board ends in place, staying the boards against the metal plaster stop directly above.

What material would you suggest? Is there something both relatively easy to form and cut, with a forgiving, neutral appearance that will not draw attention to itself?

Comment: This question is likely off-topic for several reasons but why not cut thin strips of the same hardwood flooring (it could be painted/stained for contrast if desired) and attach them to the stem wall? For that matter, you might be able to paint the stub wall to pretty it up. You won't want to _"hold the oak floor board ends in place"_ as that will make trouble when the flooring expands and contracts seasonally.

Comment: Thanks @gnicko, that's certainly a possibility. One point -- I don't want to fasten the floor to the thin strips for the reason you note, but would like to hold the floorboard ends down from above. That is, shimming that can flex with the floorboard expansion/contraction, not pinning with fasteners into the floorboards. Thin cut pieces of the kind you suggest would do that. They may not even need to be anchored in the stem wall themselves.

Comment: Very opinion driven, so not a great fit for this stack, but thin white baseboard, ripped to a slightly loose fit (with a few dabs of construction adhesive on the back) would do the job. So would paint on the concrete.

Comment: I do not believe you should use a filler between the floor and the plaster stop to hold the floor down.  Should the floor ever get significantly wet the wood will swell and raise with enough force to easily push the plaster up.  BTW this question may be a better fit for the DIY stackexchange site.

Comment: Thanks @AloysiusDefenestrate, your straightforward approach is a good one.